# Ffmpeg & PHP - Small Clip with Good Quality

Tags: php, ffmpeg

what are the best options to keep video in nearly good quality while converting it to flv and shrinking its size?

I use the followin code now:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i $faila -sameq -s 600x450  -ar 44100 $file_final");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which codec do you intend to use? For smallest size use h.264. I don't know if ffmpeg supports this but if you're looking to retain as much of quality while shrinking size, it's the best option you got.

Note that it's hard to come up with a preset that will work best for all kinds of source material. It would help if you updated the question with some information on your source material, a typical use case perhaps.

Comment: I think I chose the best. Thank you for your response. :)